# C# Windows service doesn't run when using a specific domain account

Tags: c#, windows-services

I created a simple, WCF-based service in C#. I installed it, and under the Local System account it runs fine.

The problem is that I need to it to run under a specific domain account, and it does not run under this account. I'm getting the error

```
Error 1068: The dependency service or group failed to start.
```

The thing is, this service has no dependencies.

The account is a local administrator and has the log-on-as-service permission. And the problem doesn't seem to be with my code at all, because I write to the event log when Main() starts, before anything else happens - and I'm not even getting that log when I use the domain account.

Comment: you have verified in services.msc? have you checked properties of your service and under dependencies tab did you verify there is no dependencies?

Comment: Is your binding net.tcp?

Comment: Yes, I checked in services.msc - there are no dependencies. My binding is named pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

Looking at the System Event Log, I saw that the service depends on the DNS Client Service. This is not an actual dependency, but apparently when the service is set to login as a domain user, it requires this service to run.

For some unknown reason, the service was set to Disabled. Enabling it and starting it solved everything.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution, I had the exact same problem when installing an app. Services had no dependencies, but because they ran as a domain user, it wouldn't start if DNS Client was set to Disabled. I set it to Manual and it was autostarted after launching those other services.

Answer (score 1):

You must grant rights to your user account.

1. Get your user's SID (with PsGetSid from SysInternals, for example)
2. Start notepad in admin mode and open `SMSvcHost.exe.config` (in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` folder)
3. In section `system.serviceModel.activation` there is a sub section
   called `net.pipe`. This section enumerates identifiers:
   LocalSystem, LocalService, NetworkService and Administrators.
   Add your sid in this section:

   ```
   <add securityidentifier="your-SID-that-starts-with-S">
   ```
4. Restart the Net.Pipe listener adapter service

Comment: It's weird though that it makes the service crash before even creating the actual service host :-/

Comment: Try to restart your system.

Comment: I did, more than once.